# CustomPainter Path extra line on canvas

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am using CustomPainter where I need to draw line

```
class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint firstPaint = Paint();
    firstPaint.color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 0, 140);

    final Path firstPath = Path();
    firstPath.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    firstPath.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.10);
    firstPath.close();
    canvas.drawShadow(firstPath, Colors.black87, 2.0, false);
    canvas.drawPath(firstPath, firstPaint);
 }
}
```

I need to leave margin around the screen so I am using margin in container:

```
........
Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          margin:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, bottom: 20.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
          child: Container(
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: ShapesPainter(),
              child: Container(
.......
```

I need to draw a shadow under my custom path which I used anvas.drawShadow method in my build Widget, But there is a little shadow also coming over the left side, Please see the image below I pointed an error, here is pointing arrow to small shadow: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't find any solution for the `canvas.drawShadow` effect on Path, I just created another Path() on top of the shadowed path, which solved the issue, but its kind of a hack.

```
final Path firstPathb = Path();
firstPathHide.lineTo(size.width, 0);
firstPathHide.lineTo(-10.0, size.height * 0.10);
firstPathHide.close();
canvas.drawPath(firstPathHide, firstPaint);
```